# Knockout Custom Binding does not Init sometimes

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, bootstrap-modal

I created a knockout custom binding that helps enable bootstrap's modal functionality.  However, sometimes the init method is not called when the markup uses the binding.

```
// data-bind="bootstrapModal: {viewModel: {isOpen: ko.observable(false)}, backdrop: 'static'}"
ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapModal = {
    init: function (elem, value) {
        debugger; // added for debugging

        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value()),
            viewModel = options.viewModel,
            backdrop = options.backdrop;

        /* added for debugging */
        console.log('Attaching boostrapModal binding to view model.');
        console.log(viewModel);

        debugger;
        /* end added for debugging */

        // do not allow backdrop = true for now; it doesn't sync with the view model
        if (backdrop === undefined || backdrop === true) {
            backdrop = 'static';
        }

        if (viewModel.isOpen()) {
            $(elem).modal({ show: true, backdrop: backdrop });
        }

        viewModel.isOpen.subscribe(function (newVal) {
            console.log('View model open toggle.');
            if (newVal) {
                $(elem).modal({ show: newVal, backdrop: backdrop });
            } else {
                $(elem).modal('hide');
            }
        });
    }
};
```

This is used with the following markup:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-bind="bootstrapModal: { viewModel: $data, backdrop: 'static' }, with: $data">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    ... rest of modal markup
```

$data is a view model with an isOpen observable boolean property (among other things).

In the same page, we're using require to bring in the scripts like:

```
<script>
    requirejs(['knockout', 'NavViewModel'],
        function (ko, nav) {

            // investigating the binding handlers, bootstrapModal is available
            console.log(ko.bindingHandlers);
            debugger;

            ko.applyBindings(nav.NavViewModel.getInstance(), document.getElementById('navContainer'));
        });
</script>
```

We are using ASP.NET MVC's bundler to create a bundle with both knockout and all our custom bindings so that they are downloaded together.

```
BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/knockout.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/jquery-1.12.3.min.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/bootstrap.min.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js")
            .Include("~/scripts/knockout.customBindings.js"));
```

This is not exactly how it really is setup, but effectively the same.  Requiring 'knockout' will download the bundle knockout.js which contains jquery, bootstrap, knockout, and the custom bindings.

So, before bindings occur, the binding handler is available in ko.bindingHandlers.  However, the break point in the custom bindings (first line of init function) is not always hit.  In FF, I rarely observe the error.  In Chrome, it's almost every time.  Refreshing the page over and over will eventually notice both the working and broken states in both browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the script is below the markup that it affects, it would only sometimes actually apply the binding.  Moving the applyBindings call into DOM ready callback fixed the issue.

```
<script>
    requirejs(['jquery', 'knockout', 'NavViewModel'],
        function ($, ko, nav) {

            $(function() {
                ko.applyBindings(nav.NavViewModel.getInstance(), document.getElementById('navContainer'));
            });
        });
</script>
```