# bindingHandlers is not firing with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I can't make the fileSrc (bindingHandlers) update when the input type file changed and the data has already been created (obtained from the model), only when a new element is created I can see that when I change the File is updated the other two fields )

```js
function PatientInsuranceCarrierImage(plainInsuranceImage) {
        var self = this;
        
        self.ImageSrcName = ko.observable(plainInsuranceImage.ImageSrcName);
        self.FileName = ko.observable(plainInsuranceImage.FileName);
              
    }
    
    function PatientInsuranceCarrierImageViewModel(items) {
        var self = this;
        
        self.PatientInsuranceCarrierImages = ko.observableArray(items.map(i => new PatientInsuranceCarrierImage(i)));
        
              
        const newPatientInsuranceCarrierImage = {
            FileName: "test",
            ImageSrcName: "asdfa",
        };

               
         // Operations
   
        self.addpatientInsuranceCarrierImage = function() {
            self.PatientInsuranceCarrierImages.push(new PatientInsuranceCarrierImage(newPatientInsuranceCarrierImage));
        }
        
    }
    
var plainImages = JSON.parse('[{\"FileName\":\"dtreal.png\",\"ImageSrcName\":\"dtreal\"}]');
var patientInsuranceCarrierImagesViewModel = new PatientInsuranceCarrierImageViewModel(plainImages);
    ko.applyBindings(patientInsuranceCarrierImagesViewModel);
    
    
    ko.bindingHandlers.fileSrc = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
                var reader = new FileReader();  
                //var $changed_input = $(this),
                //    file_extension = $changed_input.val().match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1].toLowerCase(),
                //    allowed_extensions = new RegExp($changed_input.attr('accept').replace(/,/g, "$|^").replace(/\./g, "").toLowerCase());

                //if (!file_extension.match(allowed_extensions)) {
                //    alert('Please do not try to upload files with the extension "' + file_extension + '".');
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var value = valueAccessor();
                    value.ImageSrcName(e.target.result);
                    value.FileName(element.files[0].name)
                }
                 
                reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]); 
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
            // and again whenever any observables/computeds that are accessed change
            // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var value = valueAccessor();
                    value.ImageSrcName(e.target.result);
                    value.FileName(element.files[0].name)
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
            });
        }
    };
```

```css
    .thumbnail{
        height: 80px;
        margin: 10px; 
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float: right; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 5px;">
           <a data-bind="click: addpatientInsuranceCarrierImage" href="#" class="button">Add New Image</a>
</div>
        
<table id="patientInsuranceImages" style="width: 100%;" class="alt1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="Table_Top" style="width: 100px; text-align: center;">
                        Preview
                    </th>
                    <th class="Table_Top" style="width: 80px; text-align: center;">
                        File Name
                    </th>  
                       <th class="Table_Top" style="width: 200px; text-align: center;">
                    </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
         <!-- ko if: PatientInsuranceCarrierImages().length > 0 -->
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: PatientInsuranceCarrierImages">
            <tr>  
                    <td>
                        <img src="." class="thumbnail" data-bind="attr:{src:ImageSrcName}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: FileName, attr:{name:'images[' + $index() + '].FileName'}" />
                        <span data-bind="text: FileName"></span>
                    </td>
                <td>
                     
              <input type="file"  
                            data-bind="fileSrc: { ImageSrcName: ImageSrcName, FileName: FileName }, attr: {name: 'images[' + $index() + '].InputFile'}" />
                </td>                
            </tr>    
        </tbody>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

After try this response I do the same and applyBindings below the handlers and it works now

[Knockout Custom Binding does not Init sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578455/knockout-custom-binding-does-not-init-sometimes)

```js
    
    ko.bindingHandlers.fileSrc = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
                var reader = new FileReader();  
                //var $changed_input = $(this),
                //    file_extension = $changed_input.val().match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1].toLowerCase(),
                //    allowed_extensions = new RegExp($changed_input.attr('accept').replace(/,/g, "$|^").replace(/\./g, "").toLowerCase());

                //if (!file_extension.match(allowed_extensions)) {
                //    alert('Please do not try to upload files with the extension "' + file_extension + '".');
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var value = valueAccessor();
                    value.ImageSrcName(e.target.result);
                    value.FileName(element.files[0].name)
                }
                 
                reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]); 
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
            // and again whenever any observables/computeds that are accessed change
            // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var value = valueAccessor();
                    value.ImageSrcName(e.target.result);
                    value.FileName(element.files[0].name)
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
            });
        }
    };
    
    
    function PatientInsuranceCarrierImage(plainInsuranceImage) {
        var self = this;
        
        self.ImageSrcName = ko.observable(plainInsuranceImage.ImageSrcName);
        self.FileName = ko.observable(plainInsuranceImage.FileName);
              
    }
    
    function PatientInsuranceCarrierImageViewModel(items) {
        var self = this;
        
        self.PatientInsuranceCarrierImages = ko.observableArray(items.map(i => new PatientInsuranceCarrierImage(i)));
        
              
        const newPatientInsuranceCarrierImage = {
            FileName: "test",
            ImageSrcName: "asdfa",
        };

               
         // Operations
   
        self.addpatientInsuranceCarrierImage = function() {
            self.PatientInsuranceCarrierImages.push(new PatientInsuranceCarrierImage(newPatientInsuranceCarrierImage));
        }
        
    }
    
var plainImages = JSON.parse('[{\"FileName\":\"dtreal.png\",\"ImageSrcName\":\"dtreal\"}]');
var patientInsuranceCarrierImagesViewModel = new PatientInsuranceCarrierImageViewModel(plainImages);
    ko.applyBindings(patientInsuranceCarrierImagesViewModel);
```

```css
.thumbnail{
        height: 80px;
        margin: 10px; 
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float: right; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 5px;">
           <a data-bind="click: addpatientInsuranceCarrierImage" href="#" class="button">Add New Image</a>
</div>
        
<table id="patientInsuranceImages" style="width: 100%;" class="alt1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="Table_Top" style="width: 100px; text-align: center;">
                        Preview
                    </th>
                    <th class="Table_Top" style="width: 80px; text-align: center;">
                        File Name
                    </th>  
                       <th class="Table_Top" style="width: 200px; text-align: center;">
                    </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
         <!-- ko if: PatientInsuranceCarrierImages().length > 0 -->
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: PatientInsuranceCarrierImages">
            <tr>  
                    <td>
                        <img src="." class="thumbnail" data-bind="attr:{src:ImageSrcName}"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: FileName, attr:{name:'images[' + $index() + '].FileName'}" />
                        <span data-bind="text: FileName"></span>
                    </td>
                <td>
                     
              <input type="file"  
                            data-bind="fileSrc: { ImageSrcName: ImageSrcName, FileName: FileName }, attr: {name: 'images[' + $index() + '].InputFile'}" />
                </td>                
            </tr>    
        </tbody>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </table>
```